# Loop through several lists of different size in Java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

My problem is that I have a function that receives a number of ArrayList's, and I want to loop through them all, but I don't know how many they will be, it can be any number of ArrayList's.

Besides, the ArrayList's have different sizes, and their sizes can also be anything.

I could not find people with a similar problem, all I found was people who already knew the number of ArrayList's or the size of the ArrayList's.

Just to illustrate, I will show a possible situation:

```
    class A{
        public ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    class C{
        public ArrayList<A> A_objects = new ArrayList<>();
        public void print(){
            // Print all combinations of chars from the A_objects
        }
    }

    A a1 = new A();
    A a2 = new A();

    a1.chars.add("x");
    a1.chars.add("y");

    a2.chars.add("X");
    a2.chars.add("Y");
    a2.chars.add("Z");

    C c1 = new C();
    c1.A_objects.add(a1);
    c1.A_objects.add(a2);
    c1.print();
```

What I want is a way to loop through the ArrayList's so that all combinations are made. The function would print, for example:

```
xX xY xZ yX yY yZ
```

Note that the print function doesn't know the size of 'A_objects', neither the size of the 'chars' ArrayList's, but it has to loop through them anyway.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you all for reading, and I'm sorry if I'm doing something wrong, this is just my second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'd need to have some kind of merge method.

For more readability, I will remove the A and C classes to use only lists.

```
List<String> merge(List<String> first, List<String> second) {
    if(first.isEmpty()) {return second;}
    if(second.isEmpty()) {return first;}
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String prefix : first) {
        for(String suffix : second) {
            result.add(prefix + suffix);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and now have a print method :

```
public void print() {
    List<String> all = new ArrayList<>();
    for(A element : A_objects) {
        all = merge(all, element.chars)
    }
    // now you just have to print

}
```

This was not tested but should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want two nested loops. The first one gets each A in turn, and the second one gets each string in the given A's list of strings. for-each loops make the size not an issue, on both counts.

```
public void print(){
    for(A a : A_objects){
        for(String s : a.chars){
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think this is not exactly what I need, I think this prints `x y X Y Z`.

Comment: As is there are't going to be any spaces at all, it'll print `xyXYZ`. If you want spaces by element, just add a print(" ") after the first for loop. I'll add that now

Comment: But I wanted the function to make all combinations between chars of the A_objects, so it would print `xX xY xZ yX yY yZ` in this example.

Comment: Should it just be limited at pairwise combinations? Or would they be of length 3 if there were three elements in A_objects?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the first arraylist then for each element of the arraylist loop through the second arraylist.

Example:

```
for(A singlelist : arraylistoflists)
{
   for(String element : singlelist.getYourArrayList())
   {
      //processing here
   }
}
```

This is just an example you will have to modify to use your class.